# Can precedents established in Native American law be used as a foundation in US law precedent?

Tags: common-law, precedent

As I understand it, interpretation of laws in the US is largely based on precedents established not only in US law but also going back to cases in England prior to US independence. This is because the US system of law is of course based on English Common Law. I also know the Doctrine of Discovery is also part of US Supreme Court precedents.

Can Native American laws also be used as precedents? For example could current law interpretation be built on precedent set by the Haudenosaunee (Iroquois) [Great Law of Peace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Law_of_Peace) that was created before US independence?

Comment: "They and other tribes after all are part of the United States." Not; read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tribal_sovereignty_in_the_United_States

Comment: @BlueDogRanch I removed that part. The question is still valid. If the answer is "no", please submit a formal answer explaining why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of "precedent" depends on a jurisdictional relatedness between a current case and a prior ruling. In the clearest case, a legal rule set down by the US Supreme Court binds courts in the US (you have to read the rule to see if it is applicable to municipal parking tickets). Rules set down by the United States Court of Appeals for the Ninth Circuit are binding in that jurisdiction (ergo in Washington or Montana) but may be persuasive in New York (since the US is still "a jurisdiction" with shared rules). The principle is that judges are obligated to respect the precedent established by prior decisions. However, "prior" is tempered by jurisdictional consideration, that Babylonian law is generally not binding on US courts, since the US legal system does not come from Babylonian law.

English common law has been a weak exception, in that US courts have appealed to interpretations (and texts) of legal principles handed down from relevant ancient English rulings. This happens especially when it is important to establish what the thinking of the founders and framers was, when interpreting the US Constitution. The rationale is that there was a shared legal system, which bifurcated in 1776, and we retain those principles that are part of our legal heritage (unless we override those principles).

Some historians have suggested that [Gayanashagowa had an influence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Law_of_Peace#Influence_on_the_United_States_Constitution) on the drafters of the US Constitution, but American law was not a part of a larger system encompassing American and Iroquois law, the two are parallel systems, as French and Norwegian law are parallel systems. As such, indigenous legal traditions would not constitute general precedent for interpreting US law.

There is a theoretical possibility of appealing to tribal tradition in interpreting a treaty between the US and an indigenous nation inside the US, under the theory that there might be multiple interpretations of the wording of a treaty. The closest you can come to that is [Jones v. Meehan](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/175/1/), 175 U.S. 1, where SCOTUS held that "A treaty between the United States and an Indian tribe must be construed not according to the technical meaning of its words to learned lawyers, but in the sense in which they would naturally be understood by the Indians", which bears on the interpretation of words like  'allotted' or phrases like 'the United States agree to grant'. There seems to be no case where an indigenous legal doctrine is cited as proof of how a tribe would have originally understood a treaty provision.

Comment: "There seems to be no case where an indigenous legal doctrine is cited as proof of how a tribe would have originally understood a treaty provision." This has been done in recent times, e.g., to determine the scope of fishing rights reserved in treaties with Alaska Natives.

Answer (score 0):

[canada](/questions/tagged/canada)

Perspective from Indigneous law and legal traditions (including anything analagous to common-law precedent) are relevant to various issues in Canadian law.

For one:

> The dual perspectives of the common law and of the Aboriginal group *bear equal weight* in evaluating a claim for Aboriginal title... The Aboriginal perspective focuses on laws, practices, customs and traditions of the group.
>
> (*Tsilhqot’in Nation v. British Columbia*, [2014 SCC 44, paras. 14 and 35](https://scc-csc.lexum.com/scc-csc/scc-csc/en/item/14246/index.do)).

Historical Indigenous understandings also inform the interpretation of historical treaties. See *R. v. Badger*, [[1996] 1 S.C.R. 771](https://scc-csc.lexum.com/scc-csc/scc-csc/en/item/1366/index.do), paras. 52–54:

> ... it is well settled that the words in the treaty must not be interpreted in their strict technical sense nor subjected to rigid modern rules of construction.  Rather, they must be interpreted in the sense that they would naturally have been understood by the Indians at the time of the signing. ...
>
> ... Historian John Foster gave expert evidence in this case. His testimony indicated that, in 1899, Treaty No. 8 Indians would not have understood the concept of private and exclusive property ownership separate from actual land use.  They understood land to be required or taken up for settlement when buildings or fences were erected, land was put into crops, or farm or domestic animals were present. Enduring church missions would also be understood to constitute settlement. These physical signs shaped the Indians' understanding of settlement because they were the manifestations of exclusionary land use which the Indians had witnessed as new settlers moved into the West.  The Indians' experience with the Hudson's Bay Company was also relevant. ...

In my view, evidence of historical Indigenous "precedent" would be equally relevant for understanding the Indigenous perspective of the meaning of the treaty.